# Meteor Package to generate fake Facebook Users

Tags: facebook, mongodb, meteor, atmosphere

I am creating a meteor.js app that uses Facebook authentication/profiles. Is there a package available that allows me to add a bunch of fake Facebook users to my app's user base for testing purposes? If not, what's the next best option for doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Facebook post for creating fake test facebook accounts: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

Otherwise, perhaps Faker.js for generating fake users: https://atmospherejs.com/digilord/faker

Comment: The Faker.js package is perfect! Thanks!